# Inserting data into a double-nested array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I'll try to keep it short and simple,
The schema looks like below...

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const QuestionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    questionTitle: { type: String, required: " title"},
    questionBody: { type: String, required: "body"}
    userId: { type: String},
    askedOn: { type: Date, default: Date.now},
    Comment:[{
        commentBody: String,
        userCommented: String,
        userId: String,
        commentedOn: { type: Date, default: Date.now},
    }],
    answer: [{
        answerBody: String,
        userAnswered: String,
        userId: String,
        answeredOn: { type: Date, default: Date.now},
        Comment:[{                      
            commentBody:String,          ////
            userCommented: String,       ////
            userId: String,              ////  
            commentedOn: { type: Date, default: Date.now},         ////
        }]
    }]
})

export default mongoose.model("Question", QuestionSchema)
```

How do i fill data in the slashed part of code?? ( i.e comment section of **answers**)
i wanted to pass `answerId` with the comment data, to somehow look for that `answerId` in whole schema and fill my data into this comment section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do achieve this using [`$`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/array.html) and [`$push`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/array.html#mongoosearray_MongooseArray-push).

Example:

```js
const updateTheCol =  await Question.updateOne(
    { "answer.userId": "user id" }, 
    { $push: { 
        "answer.$.Comment": { 
            commentBody: "comment body", 
            userCommented: "user commented",
            userId: "user id"
        }
    } 
});
```

Comment: I would floss a tiger’s teeth, that’s how much I appreciate you...thank you  so much

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70908967/how-tf-do-i-delete-pull-a-specific-data-from-a-double-nested-schema-in-mongodb?r=SearchResults&s=1|179.8125  ...May you please help me out with this ?