# how tf do i delete/$pull a specific data from a double-nested schema in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mern

so...below is the schema, from where, i want to delete a particular 'Comment' from **answer** array.

```js
const Schemaa = mongoose.Schema({
    
    questionBody: String,     //object_id - 61f59463823446723240ed85(_id)
    Comment:[{ 
       commentBody: String,   
    }],
    answer: [{
        answerBody: String,    //object_id - 61f5946b823446723240edad(answerId)
        Comment:[{
            commentBody:String,   // Object _id- 61f5946e823446723240edc4(commentId) 
        }]                         
    }]
})
export default mongoose.model("Questions", Schemaa)
```

really stuck at this for hours now...  ( ཀ ʖ̯ ཀ)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $ and $pull methods

```
const deleteACom =  await Question.updateOne(
 { "answer.$.Comment.$._id": "comment id" }, 
 { $pull: { 
"answer.$.Comment": { 
  _id: "comment id"
   }
  } 
})
```